# Creating element with attributes in jquery using older version

Tags: jquery

This syntax works in my newer version on jquery which is 1.7.2

```
sbHolder = $("<div>", {
            "id": "sbHolder_" + inst.uid,
            "class": inst.settings.classHolder,
            "tabindex": $target.attr("tabindex")
        });
```

and gives me a div element with proper id
but i need to make this work with my older version of jquery with is 1.3

Comment: make use of the .attr() function? or do it inline?

Comment: You could always build the complete element: `var sbHolder = "<div id='something' class='cool' tabindex='someIndex'>Cool stuff</div>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess creating  elements directly instead of jquery objects should work in older version of jquery...

```
 sbHolder = '<div id="sbHolder_"' + inst.uid + ' class= "'+ inst.settings.classHolder + '" tabindex = "' + $target.attr("tabindex")'"';
```

Comment: This is the easiest way IMO. +1

Comment: Thanks Bipen and tymeJV that solved my problem, it was giving me value as a String so i used it as sbHolder = $("<div id='sbHolder_" + inst.uid +
    "' class= '" + inst.settings.classHolder +
    "' tabindex= '" + $target.attr("tabindex") + "'></div>");

Comment: ok u need it as jquery object..then that is fine... anyways glad it helped..wwlcome and happy coding. :)